# need help in waiting for promises before returning

Tags: jquery

i have the following code

```
var a = ajax1();
var b = ajax2();

$.when(a,b).done(function(){
  var d = function123();
  $.when(d).done(function(){//doSomething});
});

function function123(){
    var c = ajax3();
    return c.promise();
}


return $.when(a,b,c).promise()//???;
```

How do i wait for everything to finish before returning the function?

edited:
I have test the code using the following:

```
 var e = $.when(a,b)

.done(function(){
     var d = function123();
     d.done(function(){
        console.log('1');
     });
     return d.done(function(){//doSomething});  
   });

   e.done(function(){
      console.log('2');
   });
```

my return result is '2 1'. however i am expecting a result of '1 2'.
may i know why is that so?

Comment: I dont see how you're getting `2 1` from that code. Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do i wait for everything to finish before returning the function?

You dont! You return the promise and when it is resolved (or rejected) you carry on whatever you were doing.

```
var e = $.when(a,b).done(function(){
  var d = function123();
  return d.done(function(){//doSomething});  
});
```

Note the addition of `return` - this will return your promise. By setting the response of `d.done` to another variable (`e` in this case) you have a promise that will be resolved when everything inside is resolved.

```
e.done(function(){
   //everything is done
});
```

Also read this Q/A in its entirety: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @rotatingFan Its hard to read code in a comment. If you have an update to your question (with new code) please click the edit button under your question and put it in.